# Syntax Error Debug - Unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING

Tags: php, mysql, syntax, pdo

Trying to pull off a histogram of Quote Values in a shopping cart. This query works if I paste it directly into mySQL, however I am having problems with the PHP side of things.

Error message:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in .../.../... Line 26.
```

My code:

```
echo '<h2>Histogram of Quotes</h2>';

$sql = 'SELECT 
            ROUND(ROUND(Fixes.FixAM/31.1035 * Products.Fineness * Products.Buy * Quotes.Weight, 2), -3)    AS bucket,
            COUNT(*) AS Count,
            RPAD('', LN(COUNT(ROUND(Fixes.FixAM/31.1035 * Products.Fineness * Products.Buy * Quotes.Weight, 2))), "*") AS bar
        FROM   
            Quotes,
            Products,
            Fixes,
            Currencies,
            Metals,
            ProductTypes
        WHERE
            Quotes.ProductId = Products.Id AND
            Products.MetalId = Metals.Id AND
            Products.ProductTypeId = ProductTypes.Id AND
            Fixes.CurrencyId = Currencies.Id AND
            Fixes.MetalId = Metals.Id AND
            Currencies.Code = "GBP"                     
        GROUP BY bucket';

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql); 
$stmt->execute();
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Line 26 is the line which says `GROUP BY bucket';`

PROOF that SQL Code Works

```
bucket  COUNT   bar
0       114     *****
1000    37      ****
2000    8       **
3000    2       *
4000    3       *
5000    4       *
8000    1   
9000    1   
10000   1   
21000   1
```

Comment: You can look into nowdoc or heredoc: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing quotes without escaping them:

```
$sql = 'SELECT 
            ROUND(ROUND(Fixes.FixAM/31.1035 * Products.Fineness * Products.Buy * Quotes.Weight, 2), -3)    AS bucket,
            COUNT(*) AS Count,
            RPAD('', LN(COUNT(ROUND(Fixes.FixAM/31.1035 * Products.Fineness * Products.Buy * Quotes.Weight, 2))), "*") AS bar
// Here ---------^^
        FROM   
            Quotes,
            Products,
            Fixes,
            Currencies,
            Metals,
            ProductTypes
        WHERE
            Quotes.ProductId = Products.Id AND
            Products.MetalId = Metals.Id AND
            Products.ProductTypeId = ProductTypes.Id AND
            Fixes.CurrencyId = Currencies.Id AND
            Fixes.MetalId = Metals.Id AND
            Currencies.Code = "GBP"                     
        GROUP BY bucket';
```

Switch those to double quotes or escape them in the query with a backslash.

Comment: For a big chunk of SQL I'd use heredoc and not worry about the quotes: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: AAAAHHHHH!!! Damn! Thanks, this has been doing my head in for half an hour!!! I think it needed a fresh set of eyes! Thank you. I will accept your answer as I can

Comment: The line number in the error is probably what threw you off - that can happen when you have large strings spanning several lines. Also, I agree heredocs would be much cleaner.

Comment: Switching to double quotes would result in unnecessary parsing of the string, and would still require escaping (near `"GBP"`).

Comment: @NullUserException - Yes it does, I don't know why people bother with backticks!

Comment: @WesleyMurch Is that SS on your profile from Ghostbusters?

Comment: @NullUserException: That's correct ;)

Comment: @Gravy Backticks and quotes do different things. You **need** backticks if your field names are reserved SQL keywords.